# ElementRef has no instance of style

Tags: dart, angular2-template, angular-dart

I was writing up some code which was going to update the position of a div with dart.

So, what i was coming up with something like, on mouse down on a div, start updating the position of the element.

The html will be as follows:

```
<div (mousedown)="mouseDownFunction($event)"></div>
<div #selection></div>
```

with the dart looking like:

```
@ViewChild("selection")
DivElement selectionDiv;

mouseDownFunction(mouse){
  selectionDiv.style.left = "${mouse.position.left}px";
}
```

and when this happens, it tries to call `style` on selectionDiv, but says that ElementRef has no instance of style.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected functionality. `selectionDiv` isn't a `DivElement`, but an `ElementRef`. To get the `dart:html` element, use the getter `selectionDiv.nativeElement`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: so I should update all of my ViewChild properties to be ElementRef and then adjust as necessary?   Im not saying it is wrong, but wouldnt you think that there would be a way to just point to the target?

Comment: Yeah, unless the element is an Angular component, it will be an ElementRef.

Comment: Does this allow for Setting of the properties of the native element?  When i tried to make adjustments, i didnt see anything relating to the nativeElement's style getting adjusted

Comment: It should allow you to set properties.

Comment: I think it does.  I am thinking something else is intervening.  Though, on a positive note, after monitoring everything this works. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Tobe O suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019909/4761339) the problem is that `selectionDiv` is a `ElementRef` and not a `DivElement`.

But I would like to add that enabling [checked mode](https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-2) could help you catch this kind of error early in the future. By default Dartium performs no type checking. If you want to benefit from your type annotations, you need to [specify the `--checked` VM flag](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartium#using-command-line-flags) when launching Dartium.

On Linux, you can do something like this to enable checked mode:

```
DART_FLAGS='--checked' path/to/dartium
```

Your code should now produce the following error message:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: type 'ElementRef' is not a subtype of type 
'DivElement' of 'value' where
  ElementRef is from package:angular2/src/core/linker/element_ref.dart
  DivElement is from dart:html
```

The stack trace that is provided with the error message above can tell you which variable caused the error.

```
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
#0      MyComponent.selectionDiv= (package:my_package/my_component.dart:15:14)
```